# What is the best way for grabbing command line arguments in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, command-line-arguments

I have done this a few times in c#, but for vb.net do I use My.Application.CommandLineArgs as follows or is there a better way?

```
Dim argListArray As New ArrayList

For Each argument As String In My.Application.CommandLineArgs
    argListArray.Add(argument)
Next

If argListArray.Count = 5 Then
    ImageName = argListArray(0).ToString            
    ImageAddress = argListArray(1).ToString 
    ImagePort = argListArray(2).ToString 
    FileLoc = argListArray(3).ToString 
    JPEGQuality = argListArray(4).ToString  
Else
    'TODO invalid # args

End If
```

Comment: There are several ways to get them.  Whats wrong with that you have?  In what way do you want to make it better/cleaner?

Comment: Having to use the ArrayList seems extra

Comment: He's probably looking for a combination of convention and efficiency.

Comment: They are.  `CommandLineArgs` will be available to you anywhere at on your app so it need not be unpacked.  Since you are using them right there, there is not a need to first pass them thru the ArrayList: `ImageName = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0)` will work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed...just use `My.Application.CommandLineArgs` directly:

```
    If My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count = 5 Then
        ImageName = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0)
        ImageAddress = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(1)
        ImagePort = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(2)
        FileLoc = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(3)
        JPEGQuality = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(4)
    Else
        ' TODO invalid # args
    End If
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for - Thanks.